# Смещение по сетке

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Предположим есть некий родитель с фиксированной шириной и его дочки.
Пусть это будет ненумерованный горизонтальный список.

У элеметов списка есть минимальная ширина и отступ между ними.
Если мы имеем n элементов списка, то они выстраиваются внутри элемента по некой сетке.
Проблема в том, что ширина дочки неизвестна и может превышать значение минимальной ширины.

Нужно и в этом случае выстраивать элементы по сетке.

Подскажите в какую сторону копать. А то что-т ваще ничего в голову не приходит.

Для наглядности пример. Представьте, что блоки в первом ряду имеют одинаковый отступ друг от друга и выстроены по сетке.
[image: не умеешь говорить - рисуй как умеешь]

UPD

Тут вот меня справедливо упрекнули в некорректности формулировки задачи.
Ну так, я ж не понимаю, что надо сделать, соответственно, не понимаю, как это объяснить.
Попробую уточнить.
Пытаюсь реализовать функционал для дочки:
li {min-width:20%; float:left;}

если ширина > 20%, `element.style{width:40%}`

если ширина > 40%, `element.style{width:60%}`

если ширина > 60%, `element.style{width:80%}`

если ширина > 80%, `element.style{width:100%}`

Просто правда не понимаю, с чего вообще начинать и как правильно подойти. Поэтому такая каша с формулировками.

Хотя сейчас сформулировал. Вроде понятней стало.
Надо получать ширину элемента, сравнивать с фиксированной шириной родителя, и в зависимости от полученного результата прописывать ему стиль. Спасибо Sasha Omelchenko за упорядочивание мыслей.

Но что-то от моего решения всё ещё попахивает диким костылём и нагрузкой на пользователя.

Comment: Вы уверены, что задачу стоит формулировать именно так? Получается, что сетка формируется элементами из первой строки и всё вовсе необязательно будет выглядеть так красиво, как на вашей картинке (ведь ширина дочки неизвестна даже в самом начале) и тогда совсем непонятно по каким элементам строить сетку. Пример: http://prntscr.com/dbnq3l

Comment: Подразумевается, что в первой строке ширина элементов равна значению min-width. Т.е. меньше на быть не может. Может быть только болше. В примере первая строка нужна просто для того, чтоб показать заданную сетку в 5 колонок и было понятно, где находятся точки по которым выстраивать элементы.

Comment: Можно сформулировать иначе. В 99% случаев ширина блока не будет отличаться от предполагаемой. 
Но, если клиент вдруг вместо "5 - 10 минут" напишет "5 - 10 минут в полнолунье", то все последующие элементы должны сместиться до пследующих стартовых позиций"

Comment: Попытался переформулировать в UPD. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вот примерно так можно сделать без отступов, с отступами продолжить идею, думаю, логика понятна.
`children[i].style.background = 'red';` - это выделил разную ширину разным цветом для наглядности
`margin-left: -.25em;` - это, чтоб убрать правый отступ у инлайновых элементов

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
var parentWidth = parent.clientWidth;
var children = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var childrenWidth;

for (var i=0; i<children.length; i++){
  
  childrenWidth = children[i].clientWidth;
  
  if(childrenWidth/parentWidth <= 0.2){
    
    children[i].style.width = parentWidth*0.2 + 'px';
    children[i].style.background = 'red';
    
  }else if(childrenWidth/parentWidth <= 0.4){
    
    children[i].style.width = parentWidth*0.4 + 'px';
    children[i].style.background = 'green';
    
  }else if(childrenWidth/parentWidth <= 0.6){
    
    children[i].style.width = parentWidth*0.6 + 'px';
    children[i].style.background = 'blue';
    
  }else if(childrenWidth/parentWidth <= 0.8){
    
    children[i].style.width = parentWidth*0.8 + 'px';
    children[i].style.background = 'yellow';
    
  }else if(childrenWidth/parentWidth <= 1){
    
    children[i].style.width = parentWidth + 'px';
    children[i].style.background = 'grey';
    
  }
  
}
```

```css
ul{
  width: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}
li{
  display: inline-block;  
  margin-left: -.25em;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="parent">
  <li>Один</li>
  <li>Два два номер два</li>
  <li>Три три три</li>
  <li>Четыре</li>
  <li>Пять пять очень длинный пять</li>
  <li>Шесть</li>
  <li>Семь длинный семь</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Походе на правду. И главное получилось несколько изящнее, чем я себе это представлял. Спасибо. Собственно, я просил направить меня на путь истинный и подсказать через как это реализовывать, а вы за меня сделали всю работу и предоставили наглядный функционирующий пример. Как говорится "Огромное двуручное спасибо")

Comment: @ИванМаксимов Если помог, там есть галочка "Принять ответ"=)